# Is there a fundamental theorem of calculus for improper integrals?

Tags: calculus

Let $f\,\,$ be a continuous function on $[a,\infty)$ such that $\int_a^\infty f(t)\,dt$ converges. Define the function $F\,$ on $[a,\infty)$ with

$$F(x) := -\int_x^\infty f(t)\,dt \qquad\text{for all}\quad x\in[a,\infty).$$

Can we somehow deduce from this—using the regular fundamental theorem of calculus—that $F\,\,$ is continuous and differentiable on $(a,\infty)$, and that $F\,\,'(x) = f(x)$ for all $x\in(a,\infty)$? If so, how? Are such “improper” versions of the fundamental theorem to be found in some book out there that I can reference?

Comment: Like [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=ECU9AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA387)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

$$F(x) := -\int_x^\infty f(t)\,dt = -\int_x^c f(t)\;dt + \int_c^\infty f(t)\;dt$$

The derivative of the first term of this sum with respect to $x$ is $f(x)$, and that of the second term is $0.$ You have some leeway as to what $c$ is; you could just choose $a.$

Comment: Why is the second one 0?

Comment: @mavavilj : No $\text{“} x \text{''}$ appears in the second integral, so that does not change as $x$ changes. These are derivatives with respect to $x,$ and the derivative with respect to $x$, of a quantity that _does not change_ as $x$ changes is $0. \qquad$

Comment: You could also say that the second term, if it converges, is just a constant, and derivative of a constant is just a zero.

Comment: @TheCoolDrop : The frequency with which students ask how to tell whether something is a constant is a reason to think that an answer phrased like yours may fail to be understood, whereas my comment explains what a "constant" is.