# Derivative of integral with infinity as upper bound

Tags: derivatives, improper-integrals

What is the solution to the derivative of following integral? I know how to take derivatives of integrals but I never came across one with infinity in one of his bounds.

$F(t) = \int^{\infty}_t \frac{x-4}{(x^2+4)(x+1)}$

$t >= 0$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83971/is-there-a-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus-for-improper-integrals

Comment: @dmdmdmdmdmd So I should first solve the integral using partial integration and then take the derivative of what I found?

Comment: No need to do that. Just use [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part).

Comment: @DavidMitra $F'(t) = \frac{\infty - 4}{(\infty^2 +4)(\infty +1)}$ ?

Comment: No, it's $-{t-4\over (t^2+4)(t+1)}$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Not following here, the link you provided says that the theorem applies to closed intervals, mine is an open interval.

Comment: You can fiddle with things as in the link dmd gave, then apply the Fundamental Theorem to the appropriate integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

If you want to go back to a situation you already know, just change varieble $x=\frac 1y$ and so $$I = \int_a^b\frac{x-4}{(x^2+4)(x+1)}dx=\int_{\frac 1a}^{\frac 1b}\frac{4 y-1}{(y+1) \left(4 y^2+1\right)}dy=-\int_{\frac 1b}^{\frac 1a}\frac{4 y-1}{(y+1) \left(4 y^2+1\right)}dy$$

Now, what are the bounds in your case ?

In any manner, what David Mitra suggested is really the simplest solution.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: Shouldn't that be $(1-4y)y^2$ in the numerator?

Comment: @fishinear. No, this is correct

Comment: If I fill in $x = 1/y$, and then multiply both numerator and denominator with $y^3$, I get your denominator, but $(1-4y)y^2$ as numerator. What am I doing wrong?