# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus with $f(-u)$

Tags: calculus

How would I find the derivative of

> $$\int_{-\infty}^{-x} f(-u) du$$

with respect to $x$? Am I supposed to use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus?

I try to let another variable $m=-u$ but I end up getting

> $$\int_{x}^{\infty}f(m)dm $$

and I have no idea what to do with that.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Yes you are. The Chain Rule will also be used.

Comment: I try to let another variable m = -u but then my limits become really weird and I get stuck. I keep getting the second integral in the newest edit of my post

Comment: Going off your last part with $f(m)$, try swapping bounds and then applying Fundamental Theorem.

Comment: If I negative the integral to get infinity as the lower bound, does the Fundamental Theorem work with that? That's what I'm so confused about >.<"

Comment: I'm inclined to say so. I've seen tons of different lower bounds where Fundamental Theorem was applied   (i.e. $\forall x\in\Bbb{R}$) and I don't see that being any different for infinity. If I'm wrong someone correct me.

Comment: The answer will be $(-1)f(-(-x))$. The $-1$ in front comes from differentiating $-x$. More simply $-f(x)$. You can get the same thing out of your suggested substitution.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83971/is-there-a-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus-for-improper-integrals

Comment: Alright I think I get it now! Thank you both so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

The given integral is, explicitly,
$$
g(x)=\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{-t}^{-x} f(-u)\,du
$$
which is assumed to exist for every $x$. By doing $u=-v$, we get
$$
\int_{-t}^{-x} f(-u)\,du=-\int_t^x f(v)\,dv=
-\int_{t}^{x_0}f(v)\,dv-\int_{x_0}^x f(v)\,dv
$$
where $x_0$ is some fixed value.

Then we have
$$
g(x)=-\int_{x_0}^xf(v)\,dv-\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{t}^{x_0}f(v)\,dv
$$
Since the limit is a constant not depending on $x$, the derivative is
$$
g'(x)=-f(x)
$$
by the fundamental theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\phi(u) = f(-u)$, and $h(t) = \int_{-\infty}^t \phi(y) dy$.
Then $h'(t) = \phi(t) = f(-t)$.

Let $m(x) = -x$, then $m'(x) = -1$.

Now let $g(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{-x} \phi(y) dy = h(-x) = (h \circ m) (x)$.

Then $g'(x) = h'(m(x)) m'(x) = - f(x)$.