# Derivation of an integration

Tags: integration, self-learning

Can someone explain to me the difference between the results of 
$ A$ and $B$, where
$$A=\frac{d}{dc} \int_{-\infty}^c xf(x) dx $$ 
$$B= \frac{d}{dc} \int_c^{+\infty} xf(x) dx $$

You can image $f(x)$ to be the probability density function of X random variable. So that $F(c) = \int_{-\infty}^c f(x)$

Is it correct to write A as follows
$$
A=\frac{d}{dc}\Big[x \int_{-\infty}^c f(x)dx -\int_{-\infty}^c \int_{-\infty}^c f(x)dx \Big]\\
=\frac{d}{dc}x \int_{-\infty}^c f(x) dx -\frac{d}{dc}\int_{-\infty}^c \int_{-\infty}^c f(x)dx\\
=xf(c)-F(c)
$$

and B as follows
$$
B= \frac{d}{dc}\Big[x \int_c^{+\infty} f(x)dx -\int_c^{+\infty} \int_c^{+\infty} f(x)dx \Big]\\
=\frac{d}{dc}x \int_c^{+\infty} f(x) dx -\frac{d}{dc}\int_c^{+\infty} \int_c^{+\infty} f(x)dx\\
=\frac{d}{dc}x [1-F(c)] - [1-F(c)]\\
=0+xf(c)-1+F(c)
$$

Comment: Those are two different functions, $F(c)$ and $1-F(c)$.

Comment: can you show me how to get the derivation of the two functions?

Comment: Do you have difficulties with the explanations from [the Wikipedia page on that topic?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) If so, detail those difficulties in the question. I think you should add a `self-study` tag as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your derivation makes little sense. There is no way for the variable $x$ to leave the integrals like that and those double integrals are not syntactically correct.

Under the assumption that $f$ is a continuous pdf for a random variable $X$ with finite expectation (hence the integrals converge) you can directly apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (which *does* apply to convergent improper integrals, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/83971/294695) question) to get that:

$$A = cf(c)$$

and

$$B = -cf(c).$$

Comment: I was trying to apply a integral of multiple functions like $\int u(x)v(x)$. So I am trying to understand the link you gave me. Just for clarification generally  $F(c) = P(X<=c)= \int_{-\infty}^cf(x)$ right? Is this understanding of mine correct?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. The cdf is the antiderivative of the pdf