# Fundamental theorem of calculus with improper integral

Tags: calculus

Suppose $f(x,y)$ is continuous everywhere except where $y=x$. Does FTC apply in a scenario where $x$ is given as a boundary? If so, how? Here's a general example.

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_x^bf(x,y) dy$$

There is a related post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83971/is-there-a-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus-for-improper-integrals) that doesn't answer this question. The specific integral I'm looking at is more like

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_x^\infty \frac{g(y)}{\sqrt{y^2-x^2}} dy$$

where it is known that the original integral (prior to differentiation) converges for all $x\ge 0$. I'm tentatively approaching the derivative as

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_x^c\frac{g(y)}{\sqrt{y^2-x^2}} dy + \lim_{b\to\infty}\int_c^b\frac{d}{dx}\frac{g(y)}{\sqrt{y^2-x^2}} dy$$

Comment: Consider the function $F(a, x) = \int_{a}^b f(x, y) dy$ and $G(x) = F(x,x)$. Then, apply your favorite version of FTC. The given assumptions alone won't be enough.

Comment: check the so-called [Leibniz integration rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) (Proof included).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving my specific problem by introducing a substitution to set the limits of integration to something nicer.

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\int_x^\infty \frac{g(y)}{\sqrt{y^2-x^2}} dy 
& =\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^\infty \frac{g(y)}{\sqrt{u}} \frac{du}{2y} 
&\text{ using: } u = y^2 - x^2
\end{align}

Since $u$ is a dummy variable, I don't see an issue with interchanging the order of operations. From there, one can apply the chain rule, and then undo the substitution.

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}} \frac{g(y)}{2y} du
&= \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}} \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{g(y)}{2y}\right)du 
\\
&= \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}} \frac{d}{dy}\left(\frac{g(y)}{2y}\right)\frac{dy}{dx} du 
\\
&= \int_x^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{y^2-x^2}} \frac{d}{dy}\left(\frac{g(y)}{2y}\right)\frac{x}{y} (2ydy) 
\\
&= x\int_x^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{y^2-x^2}} \frac{d}{dy}\left(\frac{g(y)}{y}\right) dy
\end{align}

So, in conclusion:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\int_x^\infty \frac{g(y)}{\sqrt{y^2-x^2}} dy 
&= x\int_x^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{y^2-x^2}} \frac{d}{dy}\left(\frac{g(y)}{y}\right) dy
\end{align}

Comment: There shouldn't be an $y$ after you have substituted with $u$...

Comment: @user251257 Hmm... I'm not sure if it changes the result. We could write $y= \sqrt{u+x^2}$, but that would not improve readability. My actual problem began with an extra factor of $y$ in the numerator, so it was a bit more pleasant. That is, I was looking at $g(y) = y h(y)$.

Comment: After substitution there is no $y$ anymore. If you are unsure, you should revisit how substation works.